# cannot connect to X server with phantomjs, why?

Tags: phantomjs

When I use phantomjs on ubuntu 12.0, the following error occurs:

> phantomjs: cannot connect to X server

After Googling, I tried:

> root@AY14021815431085179aZ:~# xhost local:root
>
> xhost:  unable to open display ""

But it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The distribution-specific package may not always be on the latest stable version.
If you don't want to install and use xvbf (for versions <=1.4 of phantomjs), or if you want a relatively recent version, with updated functionality, uninstall your instance of phantomjs and do the following:

1. download a binary here: http://phantomjs.org/download.html
2. unpack (e.g., `tar -xvjpf *.bz2`)
3. make sure the binary is exported or otherwise in your `$PATH`

`phantomjs -v`

Try running the tests that depend on phantomjs, assuming phantomjs is already integrated into the test suite.

Comment: I get the error "2014-11-14T01:13:38 [WARNING] phantomjs: cannot connect to X server" when running "phantomjs -v"

Comment: If you use the executable, make sure to check if you're on x64 or 32 bit